# How to design ancestral xml analysis

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have a piece of business validation that must happen at transform time. This is due to some of the information only being available at that time.

So what I started doing was creating an XPath that got me all of the nodes I need to analyze which I achieved. Which is something along the lines of `.//*[@attributeIdentifyingMyNodes]`

What I am struggling with is how to transverse the ancestral tree. I know I could walk the parents somehow; but I am concerned about the efficiency of this since it may be happening hundreds of times per transform.

I also need to walk the entire parental axis of a node and determine and each node whether something is true, and if it is ever false then eliminate that axis. I determine the boolean value based on a function (and for practical purposes must call this function to evaluate for true or false)

- But the trick is I only have an error if every node, identified in my xpath's result, has a parental axis that results in a false evaluation.

*I am not opposed to entirely different approaches like evaluating all of these nodes that return true into a new tree variable*

**trueFalseEvaluation function substituted for a attribute for illustrative purposes**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root trueFalseEvaluation="true">
     <someNode trueFalseEvaluation="true">
         <someOtherNode trueFalseEvaluation="false">
             <myNodeIdentified1 identifyingAttribute="true"/>
         </someOtherNode>
     </someNode>
     <someNode trueFalseEvaluation="false">
         <someOtherNode trueFalseEvaluation="false">
             <myNodeIdentified2 identifyingAttribute="true"/>
         </someOtherNode>
     </someNode>
     <someNode trueFalseEvaluation="true">
         <someOtherNode trueFalseEvaluation="true">
             <myNodeIdentified3 identifyingAttribute="true"/>
         </someOtherNode>
     </someNode>
     <someNode trueFalseEvaluation="true">
         <someOtherNode trueFalseEvaluation="true">
             <myNodeIdentified4 notIdentifying="true"/>
         </someOtherNode>
     </someNode>
 </root>
```

What i want from this is to return true, because `myNodeIdentified3` has a full ancestral axis that evaluates to true at each node. However if any of `myNodeIdentified3's` parents were false, my entire test would fail.

And finally I need to aggregate this across multiple xml documents (multiple sets of root)

Thanks for any help here. I am really concerned any solution I create will balloon my memory footprint, or crater the performance of my transform.

Comment: I could understand only some of what you want to do. But I seriously think that you shall be more specific of what you want to achieve by posting a sample output and then explaining it, for someone to propose any solution.

Comment: Well I don't want any output really. What i want to do is analyze the XML in the process of a transform to ensure it conforms to our business rules. 

Is there a specific part that isn't clear?

Comment: Wouldn't getting a transformed output with some values depicting the validity of XML against your business rules be a good idea?

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking. Should I gather up an intermediary result variable with all my data; but not in my end state? Or should i evaluate in memory at each step and then the function stack trace expire away. (My end state data cannot be used to evaluate these rules, so effectively I am doubling my memory footprint)

Comment: I can't figure what  "*analyze the XML in the process of a transform to ensure it conforms to our business rules*" means. Shouldn't validation against a schema ensure such conformance?

Comment: So the scenario is we eliminate xml elements (and all of their children) if they do not match the selected criteria used as input to the transform. However all output must have at least one table (after we eliminate the XML not matching the input criteria). This happens on many many individual xml files which then all get further transformed into a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, clearly the test you need is something like

```
test="every $x in ancestor::* satisfies $x/@trueFalseEvaluation='true'"
```

or if you prefer brevity over clarity,

```
test="not(ancestor::*[not(@trueFalseEvaluation='true')])"/>
```

You seem to be concerned about the performance of this. To see whether those concerns are real, you need to state your performance requirement, and then measure the actual performance.

The only other way of doing it that comes to mind is to filter the nodes during a recursive descent, i.e. recurse to the children of a node only if @trueFalseEvaluation='true':

```
<xsl:if test="@trueFalseEvaluation='true'">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:if>
```

Whether that's appropriate in your case depends on the bigger picture of what output you are trying to produce, which you haven't told us.

Comment: Thank you for the help Michael! I am quite new to this and I think this will help me out. 

I have been working with existing transforms and just trying to interject more checks; so the process of creating the output is not in my hand(s) right now.